# Случайная генерация двух дат до 30 дней

Tags: java, дата, kotlin, espresso

Есть два поля `начальная дата` и `конечная дата` На входе получить `начальная дата` c текущей датой, `конечная дата` должна быть выше `начальная дата`, но не более 30 дней в случайной генерации.

Использую в Android UI тестах. Крашится на `toInstant()`.
Тут:

```
val start = MakeTimeN().generation(Date().toInstant().epochSecond.toInt()) 

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.util.Date.toInstant
```

В IntelliJ Idea работает прекрасно.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.*
import kotlin.collections.ArrayList

class MakeTimeN {
    private fun ClosedRange<Int>.random() = Random().nextInt(endInclusive - start) + start

    private fun generation(minTimeStamp: Int): Int {
        return (minTimeStamp..minTimeStamp + 60 * 60 * 24 * 28).random()
    }

    fun make(): ArrayList<Int> {
        val start = MakeTimeN().generation(Date().toInstant().epochSecond.toInt())        
        val end = MakeTimeN().generation(start)
        val secondDate = SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy").format(Date(end.toLong() * 1000))

        var day = secondDate.substring(0, 2).toInt()
        var month = secondDate.substring(3, 4).toInt()
        var year = secondDate.substring(4).toInt()

        val arrayList = arrayListOf<Int>()
        arrayList.add(day)
        arrayList.add(month)
        arrayList.add(year)

        return arrayList
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val arrayList = MakeTimeN().make()
    println("${arrayList[0]}, ${arrayList[1]}, ${arrayList[2]}")
}
```

Comment: выложите код, чтобы было понятно с чем у вас проблемы

Comment: @Likhanov добавил.

Comment: Поставьте `minSdkVersion 26` и перестанет крашится.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это решение для android studio. В IntelliJ Idea есть методы, которые недоступны в android studio, хотя подсказки говорят об обратном.
Проблема была тут:
`val start = MakeTimeN().generation(Date().toInstant().epochSecond.toInt())`
Лог: 
`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.util.Date.toInstant`

---

```
class Result {
        fun generateRandomDateFromBeginToMaxDay(begin: Date, maxDate: Int): Date {
            val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
            calendar.time = begin
            val random = Random().nextInt(maxDate) + 1
            calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, random)
            return calendar.time
        }

        fun DisassembleAndTransferDate(amountOfDays: Int): ArrayList<Int> {
            val date = Date()
            var result = Result().generateRandomDateFromBeginToMaxDay(date, amountOfDays).format(DateMask.APP_VIEW)

            var day = result.split(".")[0].toInt()
            var month = result.split(".")[1].toInt()
            var year = result.split(".")[2].toInt()

            val arrayList = arrayListOf<Int>()
            arrayList.add(day)
            arrayList.add(month)
            arrayList.add(year)

            return arrayList
        }
    }

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val arrayList = Result().DisassembleAndTransferDate(30)
    println("${arrayList[0]}, ${arrayList[1]}, ${arrayList[2]}")
}
```

Comment: Причем тут `android studio` или `IntelliJ Idea` к методу `toInstant()`? Читаем документацию: `java.util.Date.toInstant()` -- `Since:1.8`, соответственно в Андроид -- `added in API level 26`. Оно и в Eclipse и в Блокноте будет одинаково доступно.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja действительно `added in API level 26`.

Answer (score 3):

Как то так:

```
     import java.util.Calendar;
     import java.util.Date;
     import java.util.Random;
     import java.util.logging.Logger;

     public class DateTest {
        private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(DateTest.class.getName());

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                Date date = new Date();
                System.out.printf("> begin: [%s] end: [%s]\n",date,generateRandomDateFromBeginToMaxDay(date, 30));
            }
        }

        private static Date generateRandomDateFromBeginToMaxDay(Date begin, int maxDate) {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTime(begin);
            int random = new Random().nextInt(maxDate) + 1;
            calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, random);
            return calendar.getTime();
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

тут ответ с примерами

http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/java/date.php

Можно сдвинуть дату на определённый период с помощью метода add(). Отодвинем дату на два месяца:

```
GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(1975,
    Calendar.DECEMBER, 31);
calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 2);
System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH));
```